# Regex to match if very first new line is followed by a non breaking space character

Tags: java, regex

I have a multi line strings which contain new line (\n) and non breaking space characters (\u00A0), latter shown for readability:

**Sample 1**

```
dog  
\u00A0cat  
mat
```

**Sample 2**

```
bat  
can  
\u00A0boo
```

I would like to return a java regex match ONLY when the first instance of '\n' is followed by '\u00A0'

Thus:

- Sample 1 would match.
- Sample 2 wouldn't as the first '\n' after 'bat' is followed by 'can' not '\u00A0'.

I'm struggling on this, all I can get is a match for both samples with a simple:
\n\u00A0 as per screen shots below. Any suggestions appreciated, I think I need to use a negative look ahead, but can't work out how.

Thanks.

[Match as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQRQ0.png)

[Do not want a match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mA4C.png)

Comment: Not sure if you meant to use `<pre>` to define code blocks on Stackoverflow or if you meant to use proper [markdown as per this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Also, are you reading from a file? Because then you can read every line using a loop, and if you find the first match, you can break from the loop.

Comment: Try `s.matches(".*\n\\u00A0(?s).*")`

Comment: Or `s.matches("[^\n]*\n\u00A0(?s:.*)")` if you want to be more explicit

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the reply but the regex is invalid on regex101.com, The \u00A0 can't be used with (?s). The error returned is "The preceding token is not quantifiable".

Comment: @Andreas See above, same for yours I'm afraid.

Comment: @elworthy You must have chosen to test with JavaScript option. You should use PHP/PCRE when testing such a pattern on regex101.

Comment: @elworthy You question is about a Java regex. regex101 doesn't support the Java flavor of regex, so it is not a definitive test site for Java regex's. Most of the time it works on regex101, but don't say that regex is invalid just because regex101 can't handle it. Use the regex in Java code before drawing such a conclusion.

Comment: @Andreas yep my mistake, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s.matches(".*\\R\\u00A0(?s).*")
```

The regex matches

- `^` (*implicit in `.matches`*) - start of string
- `.*` - the first line
- `\\R` - a line break
- `\\u00A0` - a hard space
- `(?s).*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible (matching line breaks due to the inline `(?s)` DOTALL modifier)
- `\z` (*implicit in `.matches`*) - end of string

In Java 7 and earlier, `\R` should be replaced with `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`, or to only match CR and LF endings, use `(?:\r\n?|\n)`.

[Java demo](http://rextester.com/MNI41131):

```
String pattern = ".*\\R\\u00A0(?s).*";
System.out.println("dog\n\u00A0cat\nmat".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("bat\ncan\n\u00A0boo".matches(pattern));
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

A solution with `Matcher#find` is even easier because you do not have to check the validity of the *entire* string, and thus do not have to worry about using `Pattern.DOTALL` or patterns like `[^\n]`:

```
String pat = "^.*\n\\u00A0";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pat);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.find());
```

Comment: See earlier comments - the \u00A0 can't be used with (?s). The error returned is "The preceding token is not quantifiable".

Comment: @elworthy You definitely tested it wrong, or you are using an older version of Java. See the working online demo with the output added to the answer.

Comment: I'd only tested on regex101 with javascript, so the matcher#find is the solution I've used. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`^[^\n]+\n\u00A0.*$` should work for this.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^\n]+\n\u00A0.*$",Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
System.out.println("Did it match: " + m.find());
```

Comment: With `Matcher#find`, the solution is even easier. `"^.*\\n\\u00A0"` and no `Pattern.DOTALL` is necessary.

Comment: Thank you both, the initial solution worked for me on regex101.com, but only when dropped the $ and used: ^[^\n]+\n\u00A0.*

Have implemented this solution as per @WiktorStribiżew:
^.*\n\\u00A0